# Instance show tree in haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, instance, show

I'd like to instance show function for my binary tree, constructed this way: `data Tree a = Nil | Leaf a | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)`.
I'd like to achieve a representation like "tree" unix command. For instance:

[image: Tree example]

The showing function would be:

```
> 27
>> 14
>>> 10

>>> 19

>> 35
>>> 31

>>> 42
```

I want to tabulate each "subtree" with a recursive function but i don't kwow how this is my actual code:

```
instance (Show a)=>Show (Tree a) where
show Nil = ""
show (Leaf e) = show e
show (Branch e ls rs) = show e ++ "\n\t" ++ show ls ++ "\n\t" ++ show rs
```

**So the question is: how can i implement a recursive tabulation function, because each time i use new line and tabulate just once instead of subtree depth**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a helper function, let's call it `showWithDepth` like this:

```
showWithDepth :: (Show a) => Tree a -> Int -> String
showWithDepth Nil _ = ""
showWithDepth (Leaf e) depth = (replicate depth '\t') ++ show e ++ "\n"
showWithDepth (Branch e ls rs) depth = (replicate depth '\t') ++ show e ++ "\n" ++ showWithDepth ls (depth+1) ++ showWithDepth rs (depth+1)
```

And now we can simply define Your instance like this:

```
instance (Show a)=>Show (Tree a) where
show x = showWithDepth x 0
```

Comment: No need for `concat` if you replicate `'\t'` instead of `"\t"`.